# Variable string concatenation and interpolation, string is stored in array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, variables, insert

I wish to create a piece of dynamic SQL where the values from string variables are used as variables in the SQL string:

```
"INSERT INTO `product` (`id`,`number`) VALUES (NULL,'1234');"
```

This works.

What I need to do however, is to have "variable variables"?

So earlier on in the code:

```
foreach($array as $val)
{
    $s .= ',"$val"[$i]';
}
```

This creates the string:

```
s = ,'$val[0]','$val[1]'
```

When inserted as the SQL string:

```
"INSERT INTO `product` (`id`,`number`) VALUES (NULL,$s);"
```

It returns:

```
"INSERT INTO `product` (`id`,`number`) VALUES (NULL,'$val[0]','$val[1]');"
```

Whereas it should return:

```
    "INSERT INTO `product` (`id`,`number`) VALUES (NULL,'12','34');"
```

This is being very literal as the MySQL insertion is on a loop where by $val is the array value and [0] is the key.

I'm not sure if this makes sense to anybody as I'm struggling to wrap my head around it, please let me know if my question is to vague or just doesn't make any sense at all.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Are you trying to do multiple inserts into products? Or are you missing table attributes? Cause for each value you need an attribute to go into it.

Comment: You didn't specify if this is MySQL, but I'll presume that it is. You should be using parameter binding with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). That, along with looping through an associative array will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes, so no string interpolation is done, if you want strings interpolated you have to use double quotes`"$var"`:

```
$arr = array( 1,2,3);
$i = 0;

echo '$arr[0]'; // prints: $arr[0]    <== Your error is here
echo "$arr[0]"; // prints: 1
```

#### A better approach

Anyways, you may like to do it this way:

```
$array = array(12, 34);    
$s = implode("', '", $array);  // $s is: 12', '34
$s = ", '$s'";                 // $s is: '12', '34'

echo $s;  // prints: , '12', '34'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I think this is what you are trying to do but as I said you are missing attributes.

```
$s="";

$array = array("12","34");

for($i =0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $s .= ",'" . $array[$i] . "'";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `product` (`id`,`number`) VALUES (NULL$s);";
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand from your question, this might help you to achieve what you are looking for.

On your foreach loop you are using

```
$s .= ',"$val"[$i]';
```

$val is not concatenated in correct way

try this one

```
$s .= ','.$val[$i];
```

You can split values in array by , with implode function

For example:
    $array[] = 12;
    $array[] = 31;

implode(','$array)  returns 12,31

so you could use  `$s = ','.implode(','$array);`  to achieve same result